# Two New Fields Added on the Dataflow Job from a Template

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-datastream

I created a Dataflow job from a Template (Cloud Datastream to BigQuery) several weeks ago.  I stopped the job and then tried to create a new job with the same Template (Cloud Datastream to BigQuery). Now, I see two new fields that are required (The Pub/Sub subscription being used in a GCS notification policy., Datastream output file format (avro/json)).  I have no idea what I should enter into these fields.  The tutorial on the page does not even work.

Any idea what the value should be entered into these 2 new fields?

I cannot find any documentation on what to enter into the new required fields.
https://blog.searce.com/giving-a-spin-to-cloud-datastream-the-new-serverless-cdc-offering-on-google-cloud-114f5132d3cf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nL4UuFQKy0

Error view Tutorial Image:

[image: Error view Tutorial Image]

New Fields that were Add Image:

[image: New Fields that were Add Image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a new [step-by-step tutorial for setting up Datastream + Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/implementing-datastream-dataflow-analytics) that provides all the details.

Basically, you need to:

1. [Set up Pub/Sub notifications](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/implementing-datastream-dataflow-analytics#enable-pub-sub-notifs) on the GCS bucket - this will be used to notify Dataflow whenever Datastream writes a new file to GCS (instead of having Dataflow continuously scan GCS, which isn't scalable).
2. Tell Dataflow the name of the Pub/Sub topic to receive these notifications from

For the file format, the value here would be `avro` or `json`, depending on the format you set up in your Datastream stream.